Deep Learning: Architecture vs. Features for Performance?
In deep learning, when aiming for peak metric performance, is a well-designed architecture with imperfect features/dataset generally preferable to a poorly designed architecture with high-quality features/dataset?
I know deep learning is supposed to remove human intervention that is opposite by traditional machine learning.
So I just experimented my deep learning project about signal processing. I modified some signal (feature engineering), and I get the better metric compared to my main scientific paper reference.
That makes me wonder if the dataset/feature is more critical than the model architecture being used. As we know, this is the rule of garbage in, garbage out.
So, if you have the option to choose only one, which one is critical or more preferable? Good architecture but bad features/dataset, or bad architecture but good features.
